# Load File from parent directory

Tags: ruby, require, ruby-1.8

I'm working with Ruby 1.8 and I have script that I want to call but it's in a parent folder. Below is the structure:

```
maindir/
neededscript.rb
  subdir/
    subdir2/
      myscript.rb
```

How can I require `neededscript.rb` from inside `myscript.rb`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I've done instead:

```
File.expand_path("../../neededsript.rb",File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

Answer (score 7):

In Ruby >=1.9 you can use the [`require_relative`](http://extensions.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Kernel.html) method

> require_relative complements the builtin method require by allowing you to load a file that is relative to the file containing the require_relative statement.

```
require_relative '../../neededscript.rb'
```

Comment: Sorry for the late comment but as I mentioned am using ruby 1.8.*.

Comment: Ah no worries. Just for context, I'll point out that the version wasn't in the question when I answered :) but was edited in after.  For version ~ 1.8 either of the other 2 answers are good.

Answer (score 6):

You can also add the path to the ruby libs path by adding these lines to myscript.rb before doing the require

```
binpath = File.dirname( __FILE__ )
$:.unshift File.expand_path( File.join( binpath, ".." ) )
```